# defined? for autoloadable classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails app, I'd like to check if a constant is defined, autoloading it if necessary. The `defined?` operator returns false until the autoloading has happened.

```
defined? Foo # => false :(
Foo # => Foo
defined? Foo # => true
```

My current workaround is this:

```
begin
  Foo # try to autoload
  true
rescue NameError
  false
end
```

**Is there a better way to check if a constant is defined, but also autoload it if necessary?**

---

Rationale by request:

The Konacha JS testing framework for Rails should automatically pick up a fixtures Ruby file if it exists. The loading should happen with Rails's auto-loading mechanism, so it benefits from automatic reloading (with `config.cache_classes = false`).

Comment: You might benefit from explaining *why* you're trying to do this. It might get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to create a `could_be_defined?` method which attempts to auto-load and then returns `true` or `false` as you've indicated.

There's no way to know for sure if a class exists until you try to use it. This is one of the advantages of a highly dynamic language. The down-side is uncertainty.

Your method of force-loading and testing is the only way to know for sure. Some modules may not be declared via `autoload` but in fact generated on the fly as required. Trying to predict what may or may not exist will be unreliable at best.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. What's still bothering me in my code is the overly-broad NameError rescue. If loading `Foo` causes a NameError somewhere in the module definition, it won't propagate. I'm not sure about a better way though (short of inspecting the exception message).

Comment: If loading a module causes an exception, I'm not sure that's your problem. That's a bug. You can't possibly take responsibility for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I was loading inferred constants based on conventions.  The problem I had was that any errors in the definition of those classes were being swallowed up.

I came up with this:

```
def const_presence(const_name)
  const_name.constantize
rescue NameError => e
  raise e unless e.message =~ /uninitialized constant #{const_name}/
end
```

This returns nil if the constant is not defined, or the constant if it is, but crucially allows any errors encountered while loading the constant to be raised.